# Export data from Microsoft SQL Server using a query to target data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-scripts

I know how to generate scripts to script insert lines allowing me to backup some data.  I was wondering though if it was possible to write a query (using WHERE clause as an example) to target a very small subset of data in a very large table?

In the end I want to generate a script that has a bunch of insert lines and will allow for inserting primary key values (where it normally would not let you).

Comment: What are you actually asking here? if you know how to generate a script for all the rows, why not just use a subset of those, or alter the process you're using to generate the script for all the rows. You haven't told us *how* you're doing that so how can we explain how to change that process?

Comment: Sorry, I thought there was only one way to "generate scripts".  The only way I know how to to it in `MS SQL Server Management Studio` is `Tasks`>`Generate Scripts`.  As far as I can tell there is no option to "use a subset of those".  Regardless of how I was doing it though my final goal (last sentence) is the same and what I need guidance on.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSMS will not let you to have the INSERT queries for specific rows in a table. You can do this by using [GenerateInsert](https://github.com/drumsta/sql-generate-insert) stored procedure. For example :

```
EXECUTE dbo.GenerateInsert @ObjectName = N'YourTableName'
,@SearchCondition='[ColumnName]=ColumnValue';
```

will give you similar result for the filtered rows specified in the `@SearchCondition`

Let's say your table name is `Table1` which has columns `Salary & Name` and you want the insert queries for those who have salary greater than 1000 whose name starts with `Mr.`, then you can use this :

```
EXECUTE dbo.GenerateInsert @ObjectName = N'Table1'
,@SearchCondition='[Salary]>1000 AND [Name] LIKE ''Mr.%'''
,@PopulateIdentityColumn=1;
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot and see if it does what I'm after, thanks MD.  Although your example seems confusing.  I'm not sure what I might put in the variable `@SearchCondition`.  Could you give em and example of something that might be used?  Thanks!

Comment: Ahh!!  Now I get it!  I was expecting that to do something else.  I guess that's the way you pass in variables to stored procedures.  Learn something new every day.  ;)

Comment: One last question, can it handle multiple conditions?  I have about 5 I need to apply to it.  Will this work as an example?  `EXECUTE dbo.GenerateInsert @ObjectName = N'Table1', @SearchCondition='[Salary]>1000 AND [Name] LIKE "Mr.%"';`  For that matter, how would I use quotes?  Is my double quote the correct method?

Comment: Yes it supports multiple conditions like you did. For quote, don't use double quote, just add an additional single quote in each side like `AND [Name] LIKE ''Mr.%''`

Comment: I always verify the answer works before I up vote (which I have already done) or mark it answered.  I'll get you that green check mark as soon as I finish checking it out.  ;)  - One last thing.  Per my original question I also required `inserting primary key values` just like what @SchmitzIT was talking about `SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table1 ON`.  Can this also account for that?  Currently it just ignores my primary key column.

Comment: You can set value to another parameter for this `@PopulateIdentityColumn=1` follow the updated answer. Actually there are more options which might be useful, you can check them more as i didn't use them all when i used it!

Answer (score 2):

If I read your requirement correctly, what you actually want to do is simply make a copy of some data in your table. I typically do this by using a `SELECT INTO`. This will also generate the target table for you.

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (Column1 int, column2 NVARCHAR(50))
;
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (1, 'abc'), (2, 'bcd'), (3, 'cde'), (4, 'def')
;
SELECT * FROM myTable
;
SELECT 
    *
INTO myTable2
FROM myTable WHERE Column1 > 2
;

SELECT * FROM myTable;
SELECT * FROM myTable2;

DROP TABLE myTable;
DROP TABLE myTable2;
```

myTable will contain the following:

```
Column1 column2
1   abc
2   bcd
3   cde
4   def
```

myTable2 will only have the last 2 rows:

```
Column1 column2
3   cde
4   def
```

Edit: Just saw the bit about the Primary Key values. Does this mean you want to insert the data into an existing table, rather than just creating a backup set? If so, you can issue `SET IDENTITY_INSERT myTable2 ON` to allow for this.

However, be aware that might cause issues in case the id values you are trying to insert already exist.

Comment: Thanks SchmitzIT, to answer your last question (`SET IDENTITY_INSERT myTable2 ON`), that's exactly what I was talking about.  I'm going to be using this to restore data from one database to another.  The src DB is an old backup and the dest is a DB that was altered by mistake.  So the IDs are not going to be an issue at all as they no longer exist in the dest DB.  As for the (what I consider a) work around to do what I'm trying to do I was hoping there was an easy way to just use the normal method of creating a script but adding a `WHERE` to the SRC results.  Thanks for the solution though!

Comment: @ArvoBowen Would the destination table need the IDs, though? Typically the purpose of an identity column is to guarantee a unique way to identify a record. An ID by itself shouldn't be a means to add any form of business logic (that's what natural keys would be for).

Comment: In most cases the IDs are also used for linking data from other tables.  Such as is my case.  The IDs are very important in my case.

Comment: @ArvoBowen - That's fair:)